# React app not logging to console or terminal window

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, console.log

I have a server/client react app that should be logging in the window from where I launched the app.  The client logging in showing in Chrome's dev tools, but the terminal window from where I launched the server app is not showing any output, at least not anymore.  I was running Visual Studio Code with the debugger and I was asked a permission to allow debugging, I clicked yes and now no output to the terminal window from which I started the server  How can I undo this?

Comment: Is your server app running express? Could you please add your server file here?

Comment: You may be viewing the debugger and not the terminal. Double check which tab is selected

Comment: @TrevorJohnson Not viewing the debugger, viewing the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had several processes running even though the terminal window was not running.  I had to kill the processes to allow the console logs to come through.